# Multithreaded Gstreamer pipeline

Tags: pipeline, gstreamer

In Gstreamer we are using queue element sometimes to ensure parallelism.But how we can ensure this on multicore system given that scheduler can schedule multiple threads of same pipeline on the same core ?

How do we address the above issue so that parallel processing is ensured or if it can't be ensured then how should the design be ?